# Incorrect frame numbers when pages included using pdfpages in beamer

Tags: beamer, pdfpages

I am including some pages using `pdfpages` in `beamer`. I understand that these pages can not be included a frames. Rather these are included as simple texts. So far so good.

However, I get incorrect frame counts in slide footers. Please see this minimal example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Luebeck}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage{times}

% Frame numbers
\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
  \insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First Frame}
\end{frame}

\begingroup
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
  \includepdf[pages=1-10]{mypdf.pdf}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Last Frame}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

While I need the first slide to have the number 1/12, and the last slide 12/12, this actually comes out to be 1/2 and 2/2. I know that beamer is doing nothing wrong. This is mathematically 100% correct. But from a user point of view, this is not intended.

Is there any way I can incorporate *non-frame* pages in slide counts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a number of trial and errors and code hacking, I have found the solution like this.

```
\def\getpdfpages#1#2{\begingroup
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
  \includepdf[pages={#1},%
  pagecommand={\global\setcounter{framenumber}{\value{page}}%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
      \insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}}%
  ]{#2}
  \endgroup}
```

For the above macro, the first argument is the range of pages, the second one is the `.pdf` file name. So, you call it like this,

```
\getpdfpages{{4-5}}{mypdf.pdf}
```

or

```
\getpdfpages{{4,7}}{mypdf.pdf}
```

or

```
\getpdfpages{{4-5,7,10-12}}{mypdf.pdf}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected with overlays such that there are multiple pdf pages for a single frame. If on frame 1, there is a `\pause`, and then a pdf page is included, then default beamer shows `1/1, 1/1, nothing` in the bottom corner of each page, and your solution yields `1/3, 1/3, 3/3`

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Masroor's answer, this produces incorrect frame numbers if you use overlays. To prevent this, use:

```
\global\setcounter{framenumber}{%
  \the\numexpr\value{framenumber}+1\relax}}
```

to count up by one for every frame instead of

```
\global\setcounter{framenumber}{\value{page}}
```

which sets the `framenumber` counter to `page`. The two differ when using `\pause`/overlays.

(I would have commented on that post, but I don't have the necessary reputation)

Answer (score 1):

For the special case where the included pdf is also a beamer presentation, one can use the following technique:

In the presentation which should be included in the other one, label the last frame with a name of your choice, e.g. `lastframe`

```
\begin{frame}[label=lastframe]

\end{frame}
```

Then the framenumber can automatically be added in the main presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\zxrsetup{toltxlabel}
\zexternaldocument*{OtherPresentation}

\begin{document}

\setcounterref{framenumber}{lastframe}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}

\includepdf[pages=-]{OtherPresentation}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```